# Match and coalesce multiple abbreviated possibilities

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-server-2016, coalesce

I have a table of project ID data and another of abbreviated circumstances related to the project. I would like to have the query output all the abbreviated options in a coalesced and descriptive format.

ProjectID is int
SpecialConditions is varchar

Query:

```
| ProjectID | SpecialConditions |
| --------  | ----------------- |
| 2023-0001 |        00         |
| 2023-0002 |        CBSP       |
| 2023-0003 |        KCB        |
| 2023-0004 |                   |
| 2023-0005 |        K          |
| 2023-0006 |        WMCBSP     |
```

List of abbreviated details:

```
00 = No Fruits
CB = Cranberry
K  = Kiwi
SP = Sugar Plum
WM = Watermelon
```

Desired output:

```
| ProjectID | SpecialConditions                 |
| --------  | --------------------------------- |
| 2023-0001 | No Fruits                         |
| 2023-0002 | Cranberry, Sugar Plum             |
| 2023-0003 | Kiwi, Cranberry                   |
| 2023-0004 |                                   |
| 2023-0005 | Kiwi                              |
| 2023-0006 | Watermelon, Cranberry, Sugar Plum |
```

Previously I was using CASE, then I started realizing multiple conditions exist in different order which requires me to rewrite the query.

```
SELECT CASE When SpecialConditions = '00' then 'No Fruits'
When SpecialConditions = 'CB' then 'Cranberry'
When SpecialConditions = 'K' then 'Kiwi'
When SpecialConditions = 'SP' then 'Sugar Plum'
When SpecialConditions = 'WM' then 'Watermelon'
When SpecialConditions = 'SPWM' then 'Sugar Plum, Watermelon'
When SpecialConditions = 'WMSP' then 'Sugar Plum, Watermelon'
else (coalesce(SpecialConditions, '') END as 'Fruits'`
From Projects
```

Looking for any feedback on how I can write this query

Comment: This honestly looks like you have a design flaw you need to fix as your column,`SpecialConditions`, can represent *multiple* values. If you fix the design this becomes a simple `JOIN` (and string aggregation).

Comment: I *hope* you also don't have an abbreviation like `KQ` for Kumquat, or `M` for Melon, or (a complete disaster) `C` for Carrot (I realise this is a vegetable) and `B` for Banana; if so your design is actually completely broken.

Comment: Yes looking at the data I have possibilities that are like that, for example `K` and `K7`  `S`  `SB` `SS` all represent different descriptions so it has been a bit of work to understand it. Unfortunately the implementation of the design is beyond my position

Comment: Then your design is simply broken, you *can't* do what you want. Imagine if you had KSSP; is that Kiwi, Sugar, Sugar Plum? Kabosu, Sugar Plum? Kabosu, Sugar, Pineapple? Kiwi, Sugar, Sugar, Pineapple? You have *no* way of knowing. Fix the design, what you want is not achievable as you will end up with wrong results.

Comment: I saw that someone removed the reference to SQL Server 2016 from your original post. I added it back as a tag. Unfortunately, that means that the STRING_AGG() function is not available for use and solution may need to fall back on an old `FOR XML` hack.

Comment: That was my bad, @TN . I removed the tag from the title and I *thought* I moved it to the tags, it seems I missed adding the tag.

Comment: In this case, it would be better to actually separate the "tags" by a comma or whatever

Answer (score 3):

If you define and populate a lookup table that maps codes to descriptions, you can match lookup table entries using a `LIKE` operator or `CHARINDEX()` function. The `STRING_AGG()` function can then be used to combine the results.

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, P.SpecialConditions, A.Fruits
FROM Projects P
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COALESCE(
        STRING_AGG(FL.Description, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY M.MatchPos)
        , P.SpecialConditions
        , '') AS Fruits
    FROM FruitLookup FL
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(FL.Code, P.SpecialConditions) AS MatchPos) M
    WHERE M.MatchPos > 0
) A
```

For SQL Server 2016 and earlier, the old `FOR XML` hack can be used in place of the `STRING_AGG()` function.

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, P.SpecialConditions, A.Fruits
FROM Projects P
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COALESCE(
        STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + FL.Description
            FROM FruitLookup FL
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(FL.Code, P.SpecialConditions) AS MatchPos) M
            WHERE M.MatchPos > 0
            ORDER BY M.MatchPos
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
        , P.SpecialConditions
        , '') AS Fruits
) A
```

The above will order the mapped names in the same order as they appear in the original string (MatchPos in the above code).

Note that the matching logic does not protect against accidental matches caused by adjacent codes that contain character sequences that happen to match other codes. You will need to figure out a strategy to handle those cases.

Sample results:

| ProjectID | SpecialConditions | Fruits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-0001 | 00 | No Fruits |
| 2023-0002 | CBSP | Cranberry, Sugar Plum |
| 2023-0003 | KCB | Kiwi, Cranberry |
| 2023-0004 |  |  |
| 2023-0005 | K | Kiwi |
| 2023-0006 | WMCBSP | Watermelon, Cranberry, Sugar Plum |
| 2023-0007 | SPCBWM | Sugar Plum, Cranberry, Watermelon |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GSJkmn9-) for a working example that includes both versions of the above code.

Comment: Nice solution and long time no see!